# Numpy: Get random set of rows from 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large 2D array which looks something like this:

```
a=
[[a1, b1, c1],
 [a2, b2, c2],
 ...,
 [an, bn, cn]]
```

Using numpy, is there an easy way to get a new 2D array with, e.g., 2 random rows from the initial array `a` (without replacement)?

e.g.

```
b=
[[a4,  b4,  c4],
 [a99, b99, c99]]
```

Comment: its silly to have a question one for replacement and one without, you should just allow both answers and in fact encourage both answers.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10,3))
>>> A
array([[1, 3, 0],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [0, 4, 1],
       [2, 4, 2],
       [3, 3, 1]])
>>> idx = np.random.randint(10, size=2)
>>> idx
array([7, 6])
>>> A[idx,:]
array([[0, 4, 1],
       [1, 3, 1]])
```

Putting it together for a general case:

```
A[np.random.randint(A.shape[0], size=2), :]
```

For non replacement (numpy 1.7.0+):

```
A[np.random.choice(A.shape[0], 2, replace=False), :]
```

I do not believe there is a good way to generate random list without replacement before 1.7. Perhaps you can setup a small definition that ensures the two values are not the same.

Comment: There is maybe not a good way, but a way that is just as good as `np.random.choice`, and that is `np.random.permutation(A.shape[0])[:2]`, actually its not great, but that is what `np.random.choice` at this time... or if you don't care to change your array in-place, `np.random.shuffle`

Comment: Before numpy 1.7, use [random](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html).sample( xrange(10), 2 )

Comment: why are you naming your variables A and B and stuff? it makes it harder to read.

Comment: @CharlieParker Does it? Matrices are often denoted by single capital letters.

Comment: Colon-slicing along the second axis is not necessary (`[..., ]` is not necessary).

Answer (score 79):

This is an old post, but this is what works best for me:

```
A[np.random.choice(A.shape[0], num_rows_2_sample, replace=False)]
```

change the replace=False to True to get the same thing, but with replacement.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I've edited Hezi's post to not choose with replacement. Once the edit is peer-reviewed, you'll see the added `replace=False` param to `choice`.

Comment: @SalvadorDali why not?

Answer (score 33):

Another option is to create a random mask if you just want to down-sample your data by a certain factor. Say I want to down-sample to 25% of my original data set, which is currently held in the array `data_arr`:

```
# generate random boolean mask the length of data
# use p 0.75 for False and 0.25 for True
mask = numpy.random.choice([False, True], len(data_arr), p=[0.75, 0.25])
```

Now you can call `data_arr[mask]` and return ~25% of the rows, randomly sampled.

Comment: You may want to add ```replace = False``` if you don't want sampling with replacement.

Comment: @Sarah Replacement is not an issue with this sampling method because a True/False value is returned for every position in `data_arr`. In my example, a random ~25% of the positions will be `True` and those positions are sampled from `data_arr`.

Comment: You are right. We don't need the ```replace=False```.   And as you pointed out, the number of records sampled is only approximated and not exact.

Comment: It's an interesting method. However, the number of sampled rows is an approximate to the desired (as stated in the answer). It may not work if you need exactly k rows sampled.

Answer (score 33):

This is a similar answer to the one Hezi Rasheff provided, but simplified so newer python users understand what's going on (I noticed many new datascience students fetch random samples in the weirdest ways because they don't know what they are doing in python).

You can get a number of random indices from your array by using:

```
indices = np.random.choice(A.shape[0], number_of_samples, replace=False)
```

You can then use fancy indexing with your numpy array to get the samples at those indices:

```
A[indices]
```

This will get you the specified number of random samples from your data.

Comment: Seems to be the best solution, and should be the selected answer. "*You can then use slicing*", typo: [fancy indexing](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexing-with-an-array-of-integers).

Comment: @mins "Fancy indexing" is indeed the correct terminology rather than "Slicing". I fixed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I see permutation has been suggested. In fact it can be made into one line:

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10,3))
>>> np.random.permutation(A)[:2]

array([[0, 3, 0],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 3):

One can generates a random sample from a given array with a random number generator:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
b = rng.choice(a, 2, replace=False)
b
>>> [[a4,  b4,  c4],
    [a99, b99, c99]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate multiple random subsets of rows, for example if your doing RANSAC.

```
num_pop = 10
num_samples = 2
pop_in_sample = 3
rows_to_sample = np.random.random([num_pop, 5])
random_numbers = np.random.random([num_samples, num_pop])
samples = np.argsort(random_numbers, axis=1)[:, :pop_in_sample]
# will be shape [num_samples, pop_in_sample, 5]
row_subsets = rows_to_sample[samples, :]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way of doing it is by using the `choice` method of the `Generator` class, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10835

```py
import numpy as np

# generate the random array
A = np.random.randint(5, size=(10,3))

# use the choice method of the Generator class
rng = np.random.default_rng()
A_sampled = rng.choice(A, 2)
```

leading to a sampled data,

```py
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 1]])
```

The running time is also profiled compared as follows,

```py
%timeit rng.choice(A, 2)
15.1 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.random.permutation(A)[:2]
4.22 µs ± 83.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit A[np.random.randint(A.shape[0], size=2), :]
10.6 µs ± 418 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But when the array goes big, `A = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,300))`. working on the index is the best way.

```py
%timeit A[np.random.randint(A.shape[0], size=50), :]
17.6 µs ± 657 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit rng.choice(A, 50)
22.3 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.random.permutation(A)[:50]
143 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

***So the `permutation` method seems to be the most efficient one when your array is small while working on the index is the optimal solution when your array goes big.***

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same rows but just a random sample then,

```
import random
new_array = random.sample(old_array,x)
```

Here x, has to be an 'int' defining the number of rows you want to randomly pick.

Comment: This only works if  `old_array` is a sequence or a set, not a numpy array [link] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences)

Answer (score 1):

I am quite surprised that this much easier to read solution has not been proposed after more than 10 years :

```
import random

b = np.array(
    random.choices(a, k=2)
)
```

Edit : Ah, maybe because it was only introduced in Python 3.6, but still…

Comment: How does this compare in speed to the numpy random generator?