# From a 2D array, create 2nd 2D array of Unique(non-repeated) random selected values from 1st array (values not shared among rows) without using a loop

Tags: python, numpy

This is a follow up on this question.

[From a 2d array, create another 2d array composed of randomly selected values from original array (values not shared among rows) without using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981752/from-a-2d-array-create-another-2d-array-composed-of-randomly-selected-values-fr)

I am looking for a way to create a 2D array whose rows are randomly selected unique values (non-repeating) from another row, without using a loop.

Here is a way to do it With using a loop.

```
pool =  np.random.randint(0, 30, size=[4,5])
seln = np.empty([4,3], int)

for i in range(0, pool.shape[0]):
    seln[i] =np.random.choice(pool[i], 3, replace=False) 

print('pool = ', pool)
print('seln = ', seln)

>pool =  [[ 1 11 29  4 13]
 [29  1  2  3 24]
 [ 0 25 17  2 14]
 [20 22 18  9 29]]
seln =  [[ 8 12  0]
 [ 4 19 13]
 [ 8 15 24]
 [12 12 19]]
```

Here is a method that does not uses a loop, however, it can select the same value multiple times in each row.

```
pool =  np.random.randint(0, 30, size=[4,5])
print(pool)
array([[ 4, 18,  0, 15,  9],
       [ 0,  9, 21, 26,  9],
       [16, 28, 11, 19, 24],
       [20,  6, 13,  2, 27]])

# New array shape
new_shape = (pool.shape[0],3)

# Indices where to randomly choose from
ix = np.random.choice(pool.shape[1], new_shape)
array([[0, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [2, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 1]])

ixs = (ix.T + range(0,np.prod(pool.shape),pool.shape[1])).T
array([[ 0,  3,  3],
       [ 6,  6,  9],
       [12, 14, 14],
       [16, 17, 16]])

pool.flatten()[ixs].reshape(new_shape)
array([[ 4, 15, 15],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [11, 24, 24],
       [ 6, 13,  6]])
```

I am looking for a method that does not use a loop, and if a particular value from a row is selected, that value can Not be selected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way without explicit looping. However, it requires generating an array of random numbers of the size of the original array. That said, the generation is done using compiled code so it should be pretty fast. It can fail if you happen to generate two identical numbers, but the chance of that happening is essentially zero.

```
m,n = 4,5 
pool =  np.random.randint(0, 30, size=[m,n])

new_width = 3
mask = np.argsort(np.random.rand(m,n))<new_width

pool[mask].reshape(m,3)
```

**How it works:**
We generate a random array of floats, and argsort it. By default, when `artsort` is applied to a 2d array it is applied along axis 1 so the value of the `i,j` entry of the argsorted list is what place the `j`-th entry of the `i`-th row would appear if you sorted the `i`-th row.

We then find all the values in this array where the entries whose values are less than `new_width`. Each row contains the numbers `0,...,n-1` in a random order, so exactly `new_width` of them will be less than `new_width`. This means each row of `mask` will have exactly `new_width` number of entries which are `True`, and the rest will be `False` (when you use a boolean operator between a ndarray and a scalar it applies it component-wise).

Finally, the boolean mask is applied to the original data to grab `new_width` many entries from each row.

You could also use `np.vectorize` for your loop solution, although that is just shorthand for a loop.

Comment: What does the part `<new_width` do? It is a bit tricky to look up this function on google

Comment: nm figured it out. It's a boolean operator for anyone else reading. Brilliant solution tch!

Comment: "It can fail if you happen to generate two identical numbers, but the chance of that happening is essentially zero." are you talking about a situation where `np.random.rand(m,n)` generates two identical numbers? Even at that situation, `argsort` seems just to sort whichever number came first. Example `may = np.argsort([2.001, 2.001])`, output: `[0 1]`

Comment: Yeah, that's what i meant. I guess it just biases the probabilities a bit, since a collision would mean you are less likely to get numbers in later columns.