# How to force numpy to interpret 2 dimensional array as 1 dimensional

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

My problem:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

bla = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
np.random.choice(bla,size=3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1122, in mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Now from what I understand numpy doesn't think of the tuples as objects inside my 1-dimensional array but as another array, turning the entire thin 2 dimensional. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to pick a sample of the tuples of size n without replacement from bla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that numpy can accept only 1-D arrays, while you have a 2-D array (cause of tuple); to overcome this problem, if you need tuples, you can choice a random index in the interval and then get the element from that index.

```
idx = np.random.choice(len(bla))
elem = bla[idx]
```

Comment: Thank you, this together with: test = np.random.choice(len(bla),size=4,replace=False); x = [bla[i] for i in test] solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

This Can help may be

[Numpy: Get random set of rows from 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262654/numpy-get-random-set-of-rows-from-2d-array)

```
bla = np.random.randint(2, size=(8,3))
bla[np.random.choice(bla.shape[0], 3, replace=False), :]
```

Comment: This becomes awkward if I want to use the replacement=False flag from np.random.choice

Comment: fixed it for with and without replacement.