# Get random 2D slices from a 3D NumPy array orthogonally across each dimension

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, orthogonal

I am trying to randomly sample 30% of a NumPy array of shape `(790, 64, 64, 1)`. The last dimension is the channel info for the image so essentially it's a 3D image. The intention is to generate 2D slices orthogonally across each dimension in a random way so as to get 30% of the total information of the original.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262654/numpy-get-random-set-of-rows-from-2d-array/53866936#53866936) to understand how to randomly generate slices but I'm being unable to extend it to my use case.

So far I'm only able to generate the size of the data I would need.

```py
dim1_len = 0.3 * img.shape[0]
dim2_len = 0.3 * img.shape[1]
dim3_len = 0.3 * img.shape[2]
```

Sorry if the question is a little broad.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "generate 2D slices orthogonally"? It would be helpful if you included sample input and expected output.

Comment: Does this answer you question or were you looking for something else?

Comment: @scleronomic - meshgrid solved it - thank you so much! +1 for the note on the reduction factor!

Answer (score 1):

First a few comments, you say you want to keep 30 % of the original information.
If you keep 30% of each axis you only end up with `0.3*0.3*0.3 = 0.027` (2.7%) of the information. Consider using `0.3 ^(1/3)`as reduction factor.
The next thing is that you maybe want to preserve the spatial ordering of the randomly sampled indices, so maybe include a `np.sort(...)` to the question you linked.

Now to the main question, you can use `np.meshgrid(*arrays, sparse=True, indexing='ij')` to get
a list of arrays which can be used for broadcasting. This comes in handy for adding the necessary newaxis to the random indices.

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random((790, 64, 64, 1))
alpha = 0.3 ** (1/3)

shape_new = (np.array(img.shape[:-1]) * alpha).astype(int)
idx = [np.sort(np.random.choice(img.shape[i], shape_new[i], replace=False))
       for i in range(3)]
# shapes: [(528,)  (42,)  (42,)]

idx_o = np.meshgrid(*idx, sparse=True, indexing='ij')
# shapes: [(528, 1, 1)
#          (1,  42, 1)
#          (1,  1, 42)]

img_new = img[tuple(idx_o)]
# shape: (528, 42, 42, 1)
```